# Sending Data from Excel to a Website

Tags: excel, vba

I have been asked to make a Macro which sends the Excel Data to a Website. There should not be any database involved. I have been trying to use HTTP Post after reading examples on this website. I have made a ASP.NET webpage which runs on localserver. While debugging the macro, the control does reach the webpage Page_load event but I am unable to see the data there.

Can anybody help me find my mistake?

**Excel Code:**

```
Sub SendData()
'
' SendData Macro 
' 
Dim sdata As String 
sdata = "Abhh" 
' 
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
URL = "localhost:2782/Default.aspx?"; + sdata 
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)" 
objHTTP.send ("") 
End Sub
```

**C# Code**

```
 using System; 
 using System.Data; 
 using System.Configuration; 
 using System.Collections; 
 using System.Web; 
 using System.Web.Security; 
 using System.Web.UI; 
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts; 
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls; 

 namespace Fetch 
 { 
      public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
      { 
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
           { 
                Label1.Text = Request.Url.Query;
                // I dont know where the data is in the Request object.(If it is there at all..) 
           } 
      } 
 }
```

Thanks

Abi

Comment: can you post whatever code you have?

Comment: You should look at the page Init() instead of the page Load()

Comment: Excel part of the code:- 

Sub SendData()
'
' SendData Macro
'
    Dim sdata As String
    sdata = "Abhh"
'
   Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
   URL = "http://localhost:2782/Default.aspx?" + sdata
   objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
   objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
   objHTTP.send ("")
End Sub

Comment: C# part of the code:- 

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace Fetch
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = Request.Url.Query;// I dont know where the data is in the Request object.(If it is there at all..)
        }
    }
}

Comment: Also, I can not send the data appending it to the URL as the data can be huge and also sensitive... Thanks

Comment: Why use ServerXMLHTTP rather than XMLHTTP?

Answer (score 1):

Does the 'website' have to be a standard webpage? Can you not send it to a 'website' running an ASP.NET WebService instead?

See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308359) & [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/aspwebsvr.aspx) on how to write a webservice, and then read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140260(office.10).aspx) & [here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19-STEP-BY-STEP-Consuming-Web-Services-through-VBA-Excel-or-Word-Part-I.aspx) on how to call the WebService via VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't give you an exact example in Excel, I'm pretty certain Excel has a function or two to lookup values from any website using a GET request. The difference between a GET and POST request is that in the former all data passed is part of the URL string. Assuming the HTTP support in Excel is basic, I suspect you will have better luck using a GET request, carefully building your URL with the data with simple string manipulation. Although I do not know the exact syntax, imagine a formula in a cell like =lookuphtml("http://some.url.com/send?var1="&B2&"&var2="&B3), where cells B2 and B3 would contain your variable values (the values you want to pass to the script). This assumes the receiving end is capable of receiving data through GET requests (not only POST requests). Most decent server-side libraries allow data passed through both GET and POST request, although YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time, but I can not send the data by appending it to the URL (which is working) as the data can be huge and sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a .NET guy but it looks very much like `URI.Query` would only show the GET data because POST data isn't part of the URI.

You might want to look at using the standard form syntax of `name1=value1&name2=value2&...` in your `sData` string and then on the server use `Request.Form` as per the examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx)